# How can i simulate a tab auto-click in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown  with item text of
Tab1  (itemValue=1)
Tab2  (itemvalue=2)

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li ng-click="setTab(1)" class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
          <li ng-click="setTab(2)"  ng-show="tabTab2Visible"><a  href="#tab2" >Tab2</a></li>
          <li ng-click="setTab(3)"  ng-show="tabTab3Visible"><a  href="#tab3" >Tab3</a></li>
     </ul>
```

If the user selects Tab1 from the dropdown then Tab2 is not visible and as if the user has clicked on tab2 to display the details
I want to auto simulate a tab click in angularjs ?
How can i do this in AngularJs ?

Comment: On change event of dropdown call appropriate function setTab(1) or setTab(2), regarding the selected option.

Comment: The title are Tab1 , Tab2, Tab3 can i also dynamically change these titles. I have tried using         <li ng-click="setTab(1)" class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" title="SetTitle()></a></li> , doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something else show be the error. Maybe you can share more code. Anyways. I've created a little example to show, how this works if you're using a dropdown or a li.

I hope this fixes your error or hint at you enough to solve it! Maybe, you can share more context.

Check the plnkr working: https://plnkr.co/edit/jsCt9ROBstC4W80s

**The Script:**

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    name: 'Tab 1',
  }, {
    name: 'Tab 2',
  }, {
    name: 'Tab 3',
  }];
  $scope.setTab = function (tabName) {
    $scope.urlTab = tabName;
  }

  $scope.urlTab = $scope.tabs[0].name;
  $scope.dropdownTab = $scope.tabs[0];
});
```

**The HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h2>UL Example</h2>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="setTab(tab.name)" class="active"><a href="" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      UL Tab: {{ urlTab }}<br/>

      <div> 
        <div ng-if="urlTab === tabs[0].name">Tab 1</div>
        <div ng-if="urlTab === tabs[1].name">Tab 2</div>
        <div ng-if="urlTab === tabs[2].name">Tab 3</div>
      </div>
      <h2>Dropdown Example</h2>
      <select ng-options="tab as tab.name for tab in tabs track by tab.name" ng-model="dropdownTab">
      </select><br/>
      Dropdown Tab: {{ dropdownTab.name }}
      <div> 
        <div ng-if="dropdownTab.name === tabs[0].name">Tab 1</div>
        <div ng-if="dropdownTab.name === tabs[1].name">Tab 2</div>
        <div ng-if="dropdownTab.name === tabs[2].name">Tab 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```